# Assigning to id attributes in active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a many to many through relationship between two models A and B. I want to assign a number of B classes to an instance of A by using their ids. I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
@an_a.b_ids = some_b_ids
```

How can I get this to work?

The tutorial I am trying to follow is http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised

with the corresponding code:

```
def author_tokens=(tokens)
  self.author_ids = Author.ids_from_tokens(tokens)
end
```

The correct ids are being sent to the method it's just the assignment which doesn't seem to work.

Comment: you said you want assign B classes but you used `some_a_ids`? maybe this is correct: `@an_a.b_ids = some_b_ids`

Comment: In your model, if you are using many-to-many, do you have an intermediate model to map A ids to B ids? I.e. in the same way that your tutorial uses `authorships`?

Comment: you can not use this?: `@an_a.b_ids = [1,2,3...]`